# Android Application Restriction

Tags: android

Is there any way to install some kind of policy/certificate that will restrict applications. Such as only allow application signed by google or not allowing any applications that require gps?

Comment: android.stackexchange.com is where you go for non-development-related questions.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you make custom firmware and probably a lot of modifications to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the place for the questions, but I'll give you the answer.
Google don't sign any applications. All you can do really is set it to only install market apps. Beyond that, it's just a case of not installing any apps that ask for permissions you don't want to give out, like fine or coarse GPS.

Comment: Is it possible to restrict application installations based on permissions programmatically?

Comment: Like Commonsware said, you'd have to do a custom firmware for that, and it's far more trouble than it'd be worth.